# sudo apt-get <download/install> python-opencv fetching different version than expected

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

`sudo apt-get install python-opencv` installs a `.so` file corresponding to opencv2.4.x, but I want the lib corresponding to opencv3.1.

**Detailed context:**

I am learning openCV3.1. Everything for running a opencv example is complete and when I run a sample python script, which is using a library cv2.so, I realized that the program is giving runtime error because of an incorrect version of cv2.so (cv2.so installed corresponding to 2.4.9 version of openCV, I wanted cv2.so corresponding to 3.1 version).
So, I think the issue is in apt-get sources/config files etc which I need help to resolve.

Below content might be useful to understand,
Output of `sudo apt-get download python-opencv` :

```
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-opencv amd64 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 [310 kB]
Fetched 310 kB in 21s (14.6 kB/s)       
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/bhargav/python-opencv_2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for your information the opencv version in Xenial is only 2.4.9 details as follows :

```
   python-opencv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Your require opencv 3.1 , well you need to install a bunch of things which can be found in other blogs. I am not gonna write all those here rather I can show you links because its very well explain over there.
[Link here](http://www.askaswiss.com/2016/01/how-to-install-opencv-3-1-python-ubuntu-14-04.html).
You can follow it in your Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/617586)

Comment: I didn't explained it here because  its all related to opencv installation. I felt it more irrelevant in writing python-opencv installation steps in ubuntu offical forum. So why I posted link where its explained enough. How you think about it.

Comment: @SAGARBHOOSHAN What happens if the site you linked to goes offline for some reason?  What happens if that post on that site is erased and the answer "no longer works" because the link is not working?  The reason we like to link to sites and include the critical points from those sites in the answer being written is so answers remain "useful" even if the original link goes away; this is why we strongly recommend linking to the external resource but including the key points from those links in the answer you write.

Comment: Well , that's right. I got it. Thanks for the delight.

Answer (score 0):

You can install OpenCv for Python from PyPI (python package index): https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

1. Uninstall previous version
2. Make sure your pip is up to date: `pip install -U pip`
3. Install opencv-python: `pip install opencv-python`
4. `import cv2`
5. Check version: `cv2.__version__`

This works also with virtualenvs.